# C++: Replace an element in a std::unordered_set to which we have an iterator

Tags: c++, c++11, stl, c++14

I have a `std::unordered_set` of pointers to some objects. The set has custom hash and equivalence functions, s.t. objects can be equal regarding the set even if the objects are not equal in the sense of "all members are equal".

Now I want to insert a new object. If an equivalent object already exists in the set, I want the old object to be replaced if and only if some condition on the "other" members (i.e., which are not part of the hash / equality check) of the objects is true.

If I decide to replace the object, I wonder how to do this most efficiently. I feel like the whole process should be doable with a single hashmap lookup. My best approach currently is this:

- First, call `set.insert(new_object)`. If that actually inserts the object, we are done. (This costs us one hashmap lookup.)
- If not, an equivalent object is in the set, and we get an iterator to it. Check the condition based on `new_object` and the iterator. This doesn't invoke any hashmap operation.
- If the condition is true, replace whatever the iterator points to by `new_object`. That's the tricky part. It looks like I can't do `*the_iterator = new_object`. The best I can currently figure out is to do `set.erase(the_iterator); set.insert(new_object);` - but that requires a new hashmap lookup for the insert, and could even cause rehashing. Both should not be necessary.

Below is a complete example demonstrating what I'm trying to do. It's a bit lengthy because of the custom hash / equality structs, sorry.

```
#include <unordered_set>

struct Foo {
    int set_value;
    int other_value;
};

struct SetEqual {
    bool operator()(Foo * lhs, Foo * rhs) const noexcept
    {
        return lhs->set_value == rhs->set_value;
    }
};
struct SetHasher {
    size_t operator()(Foo * foo) const noexcept
    {
        std::hash<int> hasher;
        return hasher(foo->set_value);
    }
};

std::unordered_set<Foo *, SetHasher, SetEqual> my_set;

void 
replace_if_lower(Foo * foo) 
{
    auto insertion_result = my_set.insert(foo);
    bool was_inserted = insertion_result.second;
    auto insertion_it = insertion_result.first;

    if (!was_inserted) {
        // Replace iff the other value is lower
        if (foo->other_value < (*insertion_it)->other_value) {
            // This is what I would like to do:
            // *insertion_it = foo;

            // This is the best I could figure out:
            my_set.erase(insertion_it);
            my_set.insert(foo); 
        }
    }
}
```

Does anybody see how to do this with just one set lookup? I would be fine with useing C++ 11 or 14 features. Thanks!

Comment: *"could even cause rehashing"* - no, I don't think it could, because you only insert after erasing, so there will always be enough capacity to avoid hitting the load factor.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude OP has defined a Hash and an Equals that dereference

Comment: None of the custom dereferencing stuff is actually relevant to the question about replacing an element in a set though.

Comment: Oh, and if you really need to do this, use a wrapper type with a `mutable Foo*` member. But it's a pretty repulsive solution, which suggests it's not an ideal design.

Comment: You may want to have a look at `std::map` instead.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, this is not possible, *by design*.

All access to the elements contained within the set are `const` qualified, so that the set can maintain the necessary structure to be able to search in O(1) time. If you could modify the elements, they could be in the wrong place.

You can `insert` the contents of `my_set` (or in C++17 `merge` the set directly) into a new (single element) set then swap them, however this is an O(N) operation.

```
decltype(my_set) temp{ { foo } }; 
temp.insert(my_set.begin(), my_set.end());
std::swap(my_set, temp);
// my_set now has foo, temp has replaced element or is empty
```

Alternatively, if you only care about the value of `foo->other_value` being placed into the set, note that you can modify an object through a `const` pointer.

```
auto ptr = *my_set.insert(foo).first;
ptr->other_value = foo->other_value;
assert(ptr->set_value == foo->set_value);
// ptr is "Foo * const", not "Foo const *"
```

Comment: Thanks. So, assigning to the iterator is off the table. However, my question was "how to replace the element most efficiently" - do you see any other way of doing that without an additional hash table lookup?

I'm currently wondering whether I can use the iterator that erase() returns as a hint for a subsequent insert() - but since the search is probably performed forwards, I'd need to do a std::prev() on the iterator first, and it's a ForwardIterator…

Comment: Your first sentence is a non-sequitur. You can quite easily have non const elements with mutatable values that you can actively change which wouldn't affect the hash nor anything else in the structure. Yes its dangerous, but the op seems full aware of this. But as the standard says it is so this is all fairly moot.

Comment: @MikeVine ["For any key `k` in a container, calling `hash(k)` shall always return the same value"](http://eel.is/c++draft/container.requirements#unord.req-5), If you mutate your `Foo k` in such a way that `hash(k)` changes, you are in Undefined Behaviour land. The elements being `const` *helps stop you trying* to do that.

Comment: @Caleth Yes I understand that. And so does op. He's asking if he mutates it in such a way that it doesn't change the hash can he just update it? The answer is you should be able to but you cant. Its not a limitation with hash-maps in general just the one specified in the standard in particular. And, imo, its a shame.

Comment: @MikeVine We are talking about a hash **set**. A `std::unordered_map<int, Foo *>` would let you modify the `Foo`, although you would then have to take care to ensure you don't modify `Foo::set_value`, if your intention is to keep that in sync with the map's key

Comment: @LukasBarth I've added some alternatives that may work in your situation

Comment: I'd say that for safety, you should partition the content of your object to have all index-altering members in one sub-struct and all non-altering members in another substruct that is mutable, and then you can easily provide a method to copy or swap over the mutable substruct. But after doing that, you have effectively reinvented `unordered_map`

Answer (score 1):

Would something like this work for you? Might not be the best design, you can optimise it (maybe have a wrapper `class MySet`) with a member `replace_if_lower`. The idea is to use a `shared_ptr` to add a bit of safety to an otherwise potentially unsafe operation.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <unordered_set>
#include <memory>

struct Foo
{
    int set_value;
    int other_value;
    Foo(int _s, int _o)
        :
          set_value(_s),
          other_value(_o)
    {}

    friend std::ostream& operator << (std::ostream& _s, const Foo& _f)
    {
        return _s << _f.set_value << ", "  << _f.other_value;
    }
};

using FooPtr = std::shared_ptr<Foo>;

struct SetEqual {
    bool operator()(const FooPtr& lhs, const FooPtr& rhs) const noexcept
    {
        return lhs->set_value == rhs->set_value;
    }
};
struct SetHasher {
    size_t operator()(const FooPtr& foo) const noexcept
    {
        std::hash<int> hasher;
        return hasher(foo->set_value);
    }
};

std::unordered_set<FooPtr, SetHasher, SetEqual> my_set;

void replace_if_lower(FooPtr& foo)
{
    auto insertion_result = my_set.insert(foo);
    bool was_inserted = insertion_result.second;
    auto insertion_it = insertion_result.first;

    if (!was_inserted)
    {
        // Replace iff the other value is lower
        if (foo->other_value < (*insertion_it)->other_value)
        {
            // This is what I would like to do:
            // *insertion_it = foo;

            // Swap the pointer contents:
            const_cast<FooPtr&>(*insertion_it).swap(foo);
        }
    }
}

int main()
{
    my_set.emplace(std::make_shared<Foo>(1,1));
    my_set.emplace(std::make_shared<Foo>(2,1));
    my_set.emplace(std::make_shared<Foo>(3,1));

    std::cout << "Foo set:\n";
    for (const auto& f : my_set)
    {
        std::cout << f << ": " << *f << "\n";
    }
    std::cout << "\n";

    FooPtr f30(std::make_shared<Foo>(3,0));

    replace_if_lower(f30);

    std::cout << "Foo set:\n";
    for (const auto& f : my_set)
    {
        std::cout << f << ": " << *f << "\n";
    }
    std::cout << "\n";

    FooPtr f32(std::make_shared<Foo>(3,2));

    replace_if_lower(f32);

    std::cout << "Foo set:\n";
    for (const auto& f : my_set)
    {
        std::cout << f << ": " << *f << "\n";
    }
    std::cout << "\n";

    return 0;
}
```

This prints

```
Foo set:
0x563e834eec70: 3, 1
0x563e834eec90: 2, 1
0x563e834eec30: 1, 1

Foo set:
0x563e834efd30: 3, 0
0x563e834eec90: 2, 1
0x563e834eec30: 1, 1

Foo set:
0x563e834efd30: 3, 0
0x563e834eec90: 2, 1
0x563e834eec30: 1, 1
```